# Add contents line in principal TOC but not in chapter TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-spacing

I would like to add a vertical space in my principal TOC before the last chapter. I used `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{1,5cm}}` before my chapter and it does the job in the principal TOC. But it also add an undesired vertical space in the TOC of the chapter I created using  `\printcontents[chapter]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}` . Here is an exemple :

```
 \documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,
footinclude,cleardoublepage=empty,abstract=on,
paper=a4,fontsize=12pt
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{lsection} 
[0.8 cm]
{}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1cm}}
{}
{\hspace{0.15cm}\small\contentspage}
[]

\usepackage{tcolorbox} 

\begin{document}
    
    
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chap}
\startcontents[chapter]
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10.5cm, colback=gray!20!white, colframe= gray!20!white,
    title=Sommaire,coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\small\bfseries\sffamily]
    \printcontents[chapter]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\end{tcolorbox}


\section{Section a1}
\section{Section b1}


\chapter{Second Chap}
\startcontents[chapter]
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10.5cm, colback=gray!20!white, colframe= gray!20!white,
    title=Sommaire,coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\small\bfseries\sffamily]
    \printcontents[chapter]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\end{tcolorbox}
\section{Section a2}
\section{Section b2}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{1,5cm}}
\chapter{Third Chap}
\startcontents[chapter]
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10.5cm, colback=gray!20!white, colframe= gray!20!white,
    title=Sommaire,coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\small\bfseries\sffamily]
    \printcontents[chapter]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\end{tcolorbox}
\section{Section a3}
\section{Section b3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would like to say that I'm not quite sure if what you are trying to achieve is really possible in a clean way as you are basically reading information from the same TOC. I would say my solution to the problem really wouldn't be optimal, but it works.

I removed the `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{1,5cm}}` from your document and added the following code instead:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\chapter{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=2\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip100pt}\fi
}
```

This basically achieves the same thing as you were doing, without it interfering with any other spacing, which your code was doing for some reason. There is still a big space in the *sommaire* of chapter three, but this can be solved easily using the following code for chapter 3:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10.5cm, colback=gray!20!white, colframe= gray!20!white,
    title=Sommaire,coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\small\bfseries\sffamily]
    \vspace{-100pt}
    \printcontents[chapter]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

All I did here was add a negative vertical spacing to compensate for the extra spacing introduced by the comment above.

I hope to have helped you with this solution!

Comment: Ok, it is not "clean" but it works ! I let the question "unanswerd" if someone has another solution...